# AngularFire Collection Length

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm attempting to get the length of the array of a simple `angularFireCollection` and can't seem to:

```
var stf = new FireBase("http://myfirebase-app.firebaseio.com/staff");

function staffListCtrl($scope, angularFireCollection){
    $scope.staff = angularFireCollection(stf);
    console.log($scope.staff.length);
}
```

The output in the console says:

```
0
```

Which I know is incorrect. It should be returning somewhere around 5 as the length (see screenshot below for the output of `$scope.staff`.

[image: output of $scope.staff]

Any help is a appreciated as I can't seem to get past this absolutely, utterly simple JS task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the correct way to print the number of retrieved elements within the callback would be following:

```
var stf = new FireBase("http://myfirebase-app.firebaseio.com/staff");
function staffListCtrl($scope, angularFireCollection) {
    $scope.staff = angularFireCollection(stf, function() {
        console.log(stf.numChildren());
    });
}
```

The reason for this is that the initial callback function is called **before** actual assignment to $scope.staff takes place. So within the callback function you can access only the Firebase DataSnapshot object **stf**. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access the length immediately after calling `angularFireCollection`, but the actual data is retrieved over the network and therefore it takes a little while for the array to be updated. You can pass a function as an argument to angularFireCollection to be notified about when the initial data is loaded, like so:

```js
var stf = new FireBase("http://myfirebase-app.firebaseio.com/staff");
function staffListCtrl($scope, angularFireCollection) {
  $scope.staff = angularFireCollection(stf, function() {
    console.log($scope.staff.length);
  });
}
```

Comment: Just found out that `ng-hide="staff.length > 0"` works in my view, but not in the controller. Sorry for the stupid question, but I was struggling with why I couldn't get the length in the controller. The question still stands unanswered, but I'll check it off as soon as I can get it working. Thanks, @Anant!

Comment: It works in your view because the view is updated after the initial data is loaded. In the controller, you'll have to wait for the second function to fire before looking for the length, like in my code snippet.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing. I set up this plunkr, but you need to add your firebase url http://plnkr.co/edit/VvErMju2VMkmLaYRh9hs

Answer (score 0):

ah, I see it in angularfire.js. Line 298 wraps adding an item in a $timeout. That's causing the initalCb() to get called before the data has been added to the collection. I pulled the $timeout and it worked. However, then I had to call $scope.$apply() to reflect the added items. I ended up passing scope into angularFireCollection to be sure $apply() gets called. No idea what else I broke by pulling the timeout.

this is a view of the issue: [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/VvErMju2VMkmLaYRh9hs)

EDIT: 
as far as I can tell and showed in the plunkr, this doesn't work.

```
$scope.staff = angularFireCollection(stf, function() {
    console.log($scope.staff.length);
});
```

and while pulling the $timeout from angularfire.js did fix that particular issue, it caused all kinds of other headaches with databinding(as expected), so I put it back. It seems the way to go is to use the snapshot that is passed in the callback. I can't find a lot of documentation on it, but here's what worked for me:

```
$scope.staff = angularFireCollection(stf, function(snapshot) {
    angular.forEach(snapshot, function(item){
        //will let you iterate through the data in the snapshot
    });
});
```